# Find words in common between two strings faster than nested-for-loop approach in bash

Tags: bash, terminal, sh

Suppose I have a the following:

```
a="one two three four"
b="four five two six"
```

I want to find words in common between the two strings with a mechanism faster than the naive `for` loop approach given below.

```
# This gives the result I want, but is too slow.
for word in ${a[@]}; do
    if [[ "$b" == *"$word "* ]]; then
        matching_word="$word"
        echo $word
    fi
done
```

but I've found for my purposes a for loop is really slowing me down because it gets run very frequently. I'm not sure if there's a good alternative this.

Comment: How would you do it by hand if you couldn't loop?

Comment: I do not think you can get anything better than this.You would need to do n*n matches anyhow even if its a command.

Comment: `for word in ${a[@]}` is very, very buggy. If one of your words was `*`, you'd be looping over filenames in the current directory. If you want to treat something as a list, use the data type that actually is built for the purpose -- an array.

Comment: And "any subset" can be as little as one character. There's a space in both. There's the letter `t` in both. What you're *really* asking for isn't "any subset" -- you're asking to compare *words*.

Comment: Sorry, I think I'm a little confused as to what you're trying to ask me? @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams

Comment: @CharlesDuffy sorry I didn't clarify, yes I did mean words

Regarding the use of arrays, can you clarify how I'd use an array differently?

Comment: re: array approach, see my answer. That said -- how long are your lists? Can you ensure that they're sorted? There might be a more efficient answer if you can ensure that the data is pre-sorted.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy 

My lists are somewhere from 5-20 elements long and they are being looped over almost constantly. 

They are definitely sorted with absolute certainty. 

In fact if I can find the last whole word that matches any whole word in the other string I would be super happy.

Comment: Huh. 5-20 is short enough that the overhead to start tools like `comm` is going to be much more expensive than the cost of the tools themselves. I'm not even sure that a bisection-type approach is worthwhile at that length.

Comment: ...frankly, I'm surprised you're having human-scale performance problems here unless you're doing something else you aren't showing / telling us about that spawns a subshell or an external tool. (20*20==400) iterations isn't all that many.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I could be wrong about what's causing my slow down, I only noticed it after adding this for loop. I may have jumped to conclusion on that matter. In retrospect, I should time my functions and confirm the actual source of my slowness.

Comment: That's probably a good idea. Depending on what scale your performance issues are at, you can use `bash -x` to log each command as it's executed; if you set a `PS4` that emits a timestamp, then you'll have a log of where your time is going (though you need to be careful that the logging isn't so slow as to change the results -- you can't call `$(date)` without that being slower than everything else you're doing, for instance; if you're on a new enough bash you have `printf %()T` to evaluate timestamps, but it takes care to use even that without subshell overhead).

Comment: If you have sysdig (or a similar high-performance full-system tracing tool), you could set `BASH_XTRACEFD` to point to a file descriptor opened to `/dev/null`, and then track those writes to get some quite exact timing with minimal overhead (with a PS4 that prints function name and line number, if you like).

Comment: BTW, your original code will see `fourtythree` as a match for `three`. You should be whitespace-padding `b` and requiring whitespace both before *and* after the string you search for if you're going to use that approach (though I don't at all advise doing so; abusing strings as if they were lists is a practice that needs to die).

Comment: Oh wow, thank you for all the advice! Regarding the white space padding, is there an acceptable alternative? What type of issues does it cause?

Comment: In your code `a="six"` won't match.

Comment: @WalterA Ahhh, I see

Comment: @kingkevlar, re: acceptable alternatives, see `[[ " $b " = *" $word "* ]]` -- padding both sides. BTW, what did you find as a result of profiling?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy The for loops I thought were causing me trouble timed to be less than 5ms.

It turns out I had another function that I thought only got run on the initiation of the program but I poorly defined its scope and it was running basically every time I pressed a button :P (it's a tab completable program). 

It was timing at 136ms. I knew that function had a lot going on, I just didn't think it was getting called so frequently. 

Thank you so much for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is performance-sensitive, you should use an associative array to store the data type you wish to map against. This is stored in what other languages call a dict or hash-map with amortized constant-time lookup for an individual key.

That is:

```
# use an associative array for the longer list (if lengths differ)
declare -A a=( ["one"]=1 ["two"]=1 ["three"]=1 ["four"]=1 )

# use a regular array with the other
declare b=( four five two six )

# iterate through the shorter list, doing amortized-O(1) lookups in the hashed structure
# until we find our match.
found=0
for word in "${b[@]}"; do
  [[ ${a[$word]} ]] && { matching_word=$word; break; }
done
```

...making this O(n), as opposed to O(n*m); it's still a loop, but it's a much faster one (particularly if, in the event of a difference in length, the associative array is used to store the longer list rather than the shorter one)

Answer (score 0):

Feeding variables to awk with process substitution:

```
$ a="one two three four"
$ b="four five two six"
$ awk 'BEGIN{RS="[ \n]"}NR==FNR{a[$1];next}$1 in a' <(echo $a) <(echo $b)
four
two
```

Explained:

```
awk '
BEGIN { RS="[ \n]" }    # set record separator to space or newline
NR==FNR {               # process words in $a
    a[$1]               # hash then to a hash
    next                # process next word
}
$1 in a                 # process words in $b, if found in a hash, output it
' <(echo $a) <(echo $b) # use process substitution to feed vars for awk
```

Answer (score 0):

Not the fasted solution:
You can solve word boundaries by transposing every word to a line.

```
tr " " "\n" <<< "$a"
```

You can make this look like a file with

```
<(tr " " "\n" <<< "$a")
```

You can look for words corresponding these lines with

```
grep -of <(tr " " "\n" <<< "$a") <<< "$b"
```

Flaw is this solution is that `six` will be found in:

```
a="one six three four"
b="four five two sixty"
```

We need word boundaries in `$b` as well.

```
comm -12  <(tr " " "\n" <<< "$a" | sort) <(tr " " "\n" <<< "$b" | sort)
```